# Changing $\int$ and $\sum$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> > Consider functions $f_j\in\mathcal{L}^1, j\in\mathbb{N}$. 
> >     Show: If $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int\lvert f_j\rvert <\infty$, then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j$ converges a.e. against an integrable function and it is
> >     $$
> > \int\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int f_j.
> > $$

Hm, it's rather difficult to me to show that.

Let $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int\lvert f_j\rvert <\infty$. Then
$$
\int\lvert f_j\rvert\to 0\mbox{ a.e.}
$$
and therefore $\lvert f_j\rvert\to 0$ a.e.?

But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the space $X$ and the measure $\mu$.

Define $h_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \left|f_j(x)\right|$. By the monotone convergence theorem:
$$
\int \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|f_j\right| = \int \lim_{n\to\infty} h_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int h_n = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int \left|f_j\right| < \infty
$$

Define:

$$
E = \{x \in X: \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|f_j(x)\right| = \infty \}
$$

If $\mu(E) > 0$, then $\int \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|f_j\right|$ would be $\infty$, a contradiction. It follows that $\mu(E) = 0$, and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|f_j\right|$ converges a.e.

Define $\varphi(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|f_j(x)\right|$ and $g_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n f_j(x)$. We have $\varphi \in \mathcal{L}^1$ and $\left|g_n\right| \le \varphi \ \forall n \in \mathbb N$. By the dominated convergence theorem:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \int f_j = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n = \int \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n = \int \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j
$$

Comment: Why is because of the monotone convergence theorem $\int\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lvert f_j\rvert=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int\lvert f_j\rvert$?

Comment: @math12 Added more details. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now I try to understand the rest of your proof. Maybe I will ask further questions later or tomorrow. Up to now have great thank!

Comment: @math12 Happy to help!

Comment: One more questions: It is to show that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j$ converges a.e. against an integrable function. Where did you show that? I guess I am blind. :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry: Because it convergences absolutely it convergences. Then only remains: Where did you show that the limit function is integrable?

Comment: @math12 1) Yes. It converges absolutely so it converges. 2) $\int |\varphi| = \int \sum \left|f_j\right| < \infty$ by the first part.

Comment: Perfect, now everything is clear to me. Again a great thank - you rescued my evening!!! :-)